# Magento 2.4 Elastic Search Categories Emptying

Tags: category-products, indexing, magento2.4, elasticsearch

I have recently updated to Magento 2.4 and on my test site it works perfectly fine.

However, on my production site my categories randomly empty. To fix it, I manually run the bin/magento index:reindex and everything is back to normal.

I did initially have memory issues with the server where the memory would run out and the Elastic Search service would crash. I have since doubled memory and the service is no longer crashing, but I am still seeing issues with categories emptying.

I cannot see anything in the logs that indicates what the issue is.

I have also tried all indexes on 'Update on Save' and 'Update on Schedule'. When set on 'Update on Save' categories don't seem to empty as much.

Has anyone come across this?

My current Elastic Search health is yellow, and I have read I to get it to green I need to add an additional node, which I am hoping may resolve the issue.

**Edit:** Looks like its the catalog_product_attribute (EAV) index which is causing the issue. Re-indexing just this one sorts the error

**For anyone encountering this, turns out it was the CSP magento module which was sapping all the memory from the site. Disable the module and it works fine.

There is a thread on GIT for the issue: **
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29964&ved=2ahUKEwjhquSO9KLtAhWMSsAKHXzdAK8QFjAAegQIBBAC&usg=AOvVaw0AJkr_XXkZRL6GsOTYs9fI

Comment: Hello, we have the exact same problem since we upgraded from 2.3.5 to 2.4.1.
For us, it is temporarly fixed by refreshing one of those two indexes : "Product Price, "Catalog Search" (I guess it is the second one). We have MSI on. 
At the beginning we had an error in log files because we didn't change the way cron was set up. Magento 2.4 changed a bit regarding this part. But we seem to still have our problem of empty categories.

Comment: By any chance, do you also use Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation ?

Comment: I've just updated the question, try disabling the CSP module, hopefully that will fix yours!

Comment: CSP is already disabled :( Thx for your reply

Comment: Is your elastic search service itself crashing? My initial problem after upgrading was that the elastic search service stopped. Then once that worse sorted it was the CSP module consuming memory.

Comment: Nothing wrong in our logs. I may have find our problem, we had 2 identical magento instances on the same ES with the same prefix.